# Removal of Notepad++ styles possible? (I mean to the Style configurator's language color styles)

Tags: bash, notepad++, colors

I encounter the following problem with Unix **.sh** files in Notepadd ++:

The whole document will be colored in one single color if its contents are wrapped with an [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) command. For example:

```
**<< 'EOF0'**

Content of the document --- All of which will be dyed in a single color.

**EOF0**
```

## Image examples:

#### 1 - Without an heredoc:

[image]

---

#### 2 - With an heredoc:

[image]

---

### Why the situation I just described is problematic:

When working with very long scripts, it can be quite annoying that all is colored in one single color because of one single (heredoc) command, when you know that in the end of the day, it would be much more comfortable to have a multi-color document as it would have been without this command.

### What I tried to solve it:

I tried to go to `Settings > Style configurator > Language --- Bash` and there to somehow totally remove HERE DELEM && HERE Q, but I didn't find such way in the GUI.

### My question:

How can you remove these 2 styles (or any other style) from Notepad++ so they won't effect color of text in .sh documents? (.sh documents in my case)?

I just don't such wrappers (heredocs are text wrappers) to be colored in whatever color... I just want to totally remove their "native" Notepad++ style...

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/  I use notepad++ for some things, but visual studio code has really made things easier for me for most of the coding I do.  It's free. Try it out  on this and tell me what you think.

Comment: I just tried it.  It reminds me of c++ because it sees the << as a comment.  So everything inside the << will be a single color.  This seems to be the issue.  I looked up bash extensions too, and they have some, but none seen for heredocs.  If you take out the << then I can see it all in different nicely laid out colors.

Comment: You can also update the language filter to not see << comments, then it won't break.

Comment: If you clone the sh language file and remove the section that highlights "<<" then it will not all go blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target formatting style you were trying to achieve is not easily possible (But yes, it is possible in harder way), but you can solve your problem by a simple trick also. I am discussing both here.

**Why it is not directly possible:**

If you go to your `Notepad++` directory in Windows, you will find a file named `SciLexer.dll`. This file has been built from the original source code of Notepad++. The way the `Bash` codes detect the `heredoc` commands are hard coded inside this file. And this file is not directly editable by user.

**Then how to edit `SciLexer.dll`:**

As we know that `Notepad++` is an open source software, we can build the `SciLexer.dll` by our own from their given source codes. But to do that one should have very good knowledge in programming language else he could mess up all those things. [Here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus) you will find the full source code for `Notepad++` and `SciLexer.dll` along with the detailed instructions on how to build them. So, if you have a good knowledge of programming, you can surely go through their tutorial there and you will find a file named `LexBash.cxx` in `scintilla` > `lexers` directory which you can edit to remove the `heredoc` detection part and rebuild the files according to that tutorial. Finally you will get new `SciLexer.dll`. If you replace that with the present `SciLexer.dll` in your `Notepad++` directory, it will work like a charm.

*Now the problem is if you are unable to do all those things due to lack of programming knowledge or shortage of time, then is there any other way!!!! May be not, but I found a trick which you can use to solve your problem partially.*

**Will it work the way you thought:**

As you stated:

> I tried to go to `Settings > Style configurator > Language --- Bash`
>   and there to somehow totally remove HERE DELEM && HERE Q, but I didn't
>   find such way in the GUI.

Obviously, in the GUI there is no option to remove those attributes but we can remove those attributes. To do that, in Windows you have to go to this directory:

**`%AppData%\Notepad++`** (Copy-Paste the directory to your Windows Explorer Address Bar)

In that directory you will find some `xml` files. The one we need is `stylers.xml`. So, find and open it with `Notepad++` or other good text formatting & editing tools as default Windows Notepad mess up the formatting. In that file search for *`bash`*. You will find something like this:

[image]

These are the all properties of styling inside `Bash` files. In last two lines it describes about the `HERE DOC`. So you may think of removing those lines and saving the file. By this way you will no longer see above two options you mentioned in the GUI of the Notepad++. But don't do that.

Actually, they will remove the `HERE DELIM` and `HERE Q` formatting style from `Notepad++` Bash scripts, but will not solve your problem. Because, as I have said earlier that, the `heredoc` formatting style is hard coded in `SciLexer.dll`. So, when you remove those attributes, the `Notepad++` can still detect `heredoc` commands and as it will not find the appropriate formatting style, then it will override the default style that means all lines will be black colored. Thus your problem can't be solved in the way you think.

**A simple trick which may partially solve your problem:**

Notepad++ gives access to formatting style of almost 52 programming languages, but all of them are not needed by everyone. So, my trick is to edit another language of similar formatting style to work with `Bash` files.
I have found that `NSIS` uses almost same formatting style as `Bash`. So, during editing or writing up a `.sh` or other `Bash` files after opening the file in `Notepad++`, simply select the language as `NSIS`.

[image]

That will do the trick but you can see that the keywords are still black which we need to be colored blue. So we have to replace the keywords of `NSIS` with the keywords of `Bash`. To do that again go to the directory:

**`%AppData%\Notepad++`** (Copy-Paste the directory to your Windows Explorer Address Bar)

This time, we need the file named as `langs.xml`. So open it using `Notepad++`. Search for `bash`. You will find something like this:

[image]

Copy that part to somewhere else. Now again search for `nsis` in that file `langs.xml`. You will find something like this:

[image]

Now finally replace the `nsis` part with the previously copied part as below:

[image]

And save the file. Now, Restart your Notepad++ and see the changes. Hope it will help you somewhat. The problem you will find in this method is that the variable with  `$` sign is not differentiated with other color. But may be it's not a big problem. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I gave you the bounty and a thumb up, I encourage you to edit the answer, shorten it where you can, and add some separators between preface, body, and ending. Keeping with the original concept, but as short and formatted as possible (when needed) will grant easy read for all users and will promise you more thumb ups. Don't hesitate edit as many times as you need. All of use will benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. I tried to explain everything step by step could not understand that it has become that much bigger. I will surely edit it to more user friendly way. Thanks once again.

Comment: Dear Rakibul. I don't have the NSIS language in my Notepad++ but what do you think on creating a new custom language style-configurator which will be a copy of Bash XML code but just without the Here-styles?

Comment: Ow..really??? NSIS isn't there??? Which version of Notepad++ you were using? I've tested in latest version `7.2.2` . Try Upgrading your Notepad++.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to create custom language by own, but that is something tricky and I didn't have that much good knowledge about bash. So, I couldn't do that. You can create new language and they provide nice gui tool which you will get in `Language` tab in `Menu Bar` where it says `Define your language..`

Comment: Thank you dearly, I've yet to change how it looks because I didn't see NSIS there (I use version 7.2.2 as well), but I accept the answer anyway because it is helpful and I can feel the research you have putted to it and I admire that.

Comment: Dear rakibul, you might want to try to answer here as well? https://superuser.com/questions/1193558/notepad-background-color-for-tabs-tabulations

Comment: Thanks dear for calling me up again. I am not familiar with Vim so I don't know actually how it looks like the background color of tabs. By the way I added an answer but not sure whether that was the thing you were looking for.